# BitmapFactory.decodeResource or decodeStream for different images

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a long standing problem with images (used for map pins) I am using and it keeps getting worse as resolutions get higher. If I use one image, it is fine to just have it in drawable directories and specify that image. Works find with different sizes and resolutions. However, I am pulling the image name from a database on the fly. So it is working fine to have the images in the assets directory but then it is one and only one image for all resolutions. Not good nowadays as they are too small on higher end phones now.

So my goal is to grab the image name from the database and then be able to use the drawable directories and have different sizes. It seems like this would be possible but everything I try fails.

This works specifying one image from the resources directories:

```
public void run(){
    if (!(llat == 0) && !(llon == 0)) {
        if (ests == null || ests.size() == 0
            || poisPinpoints.size() == 0) {
        ests = DBManager.getEstablishments();
        for (Establishment est : ests) {
        try {
        est_pin_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mil_pushpin);
  poisPinpoints.put(
        est.getPoiType().getPushpin(), est_pin_bmp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is used when I have multiple images pulled from the database...but it is only one size from the assets directory:

```
public void run(){
if (!(llat == 0) && !(llon == 0)) {
    if (ests == null || ests.size() == 0
        || poisPinpoints.size() == 0) {
    ests = DBManager.getEstablishments();
    for (Establishment est : ests) {
        try {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory
        .decodeStream(PlayPlaces.this
            .getAssets().open(
                est.getPoiType()
                    .getPushpin()));
    poisPinpoints.put(
        est.getPoiType().getPushpin(), bm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to take a look into this method [Resources.getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

with it you can specify something like:

```
String resName = est.getPoiType().getPushpin();
int drawId = getResources().getIdentifier(resName , "drawable", getPackageName());
est_pin_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawId);
```